# Проверка mac-address

Tags: python, django

Есть ссылка на готовое решение проверки mac-адреса [проверка mac-address](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1337/).
Я так понимаю, кусок кода нужно разместить в `forms.py`?

Answer (score 1):

Да, это созданные собственные типы полей, для формы и модели соответственно.